# HTML/CSS Not Working or Javascript - Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a simple dropdown menu but it isn't doing anything and I don't know why. The javascript should toggle the class which if off: should hide the language types and slide the other tabs up(Contact). When I click the button it does completely nothing. The class dp-click is what you click to toggle the menu. The class dp-contents is the languages which should toggle the visibility of them upon clicking dp-click.
Here is the html.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Enforcext</title>
    </head>

    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="http://www.destinygamewiki.com/images/7/72/Enforcer_medal1.png" width="50px">
            <ul class="links">
                <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 15px;"><a href="Index.html">Home</li>
                <div class="lt">
                    <div class="dp-click">
                        <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 15px" class="dp-click"><a href="#" class="dp-click">Languages</a></li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
            <div class="lt">
                <ul class="dp-contents links">
                    <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 25px"><a href="PHP.php">PHP</a></li>
                    <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 25px"><a href="HTML.html">HTML</a></li>
                    <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 25px"><a href="CSS.html">CSS</a></li>
                    <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 25px"><a href="Javascript.html">Javascript</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div class="lt">
            <ul class="links">
                <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 15px;"><a href="Contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <body>


    </body>
    <script src="Javascript.js"></script>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-image: url(Texture2.jpeg);
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}
.links{
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.links a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  color: yellow;
}
.links a:hover{
  font-family: Impact;
}
.dp-contents{
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0%;
  color: white;
}
.dp-show{
  color: purple;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
var main = function(){
    $('.dp-click').click(function(){
        $('.dp-contents').toggle();
    });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you link external library [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) in this case since you are using jQuery.

From your code it seems you are not linking it.

Plus make sure all of your content is wrapped in your `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

First set your `div.nav` inside body tag.

Secend you have some mistake in coding like:

```
<li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 15px;"><a href="Index.html">Home</li>
```

Here you have to write `</a>` before `</li>`.

Or here:

```
</div class="lt">
```

This is wrong. Here you have to add `</div>` and Remove slash from top line.

Comment: The closing div tag is correct. Its the class attribute which is wrong. Also a `<div />` is not allowed to be a direct child of a `<ul />`